# Шахматная задача. Мы с конем вдвоем по полю пойдем

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада, шахматы

Условие задачи : ([условия и тестирующая система)](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=325) 
Заданы две клетки шахматной доски. Требуется определить, возможно ли попасть из одной клетки в другую одним ходом шахматного коня, а если нет, то следует выяснить, возможно ли попасть с помощью двух ходов.

Входные данные

Входной файл INPUT.TXT содержит координаты двух клеток в общепринятом формате: каждая координата записывается как английская строчная буква и цифра, координаты отделены друг от друга запятой и пробелом.

Выходные данные

Выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT должен содержать цифру «1», если возможно из одной клетки в другую попасть за 1 ход, либо цифру «2», если попасть можно за 2 хода, либо «NO», если одна клетка недостижима из другой ни за 1 ни за 2 хода.

Итак,  у меня есть данный код, который, в теории должен обрабатывать все возможные случаи(для двух ходов коня), однако он валит на первом тесте, подскажите пожалуйста, видите ли вы здесь ошибку

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool h(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  if((abs(x2 - x1) == 2 && abs(y2 - y1) == 1) || (abs(x2 - x1) == 1 && abs(y2 - y1) == 2)) return true;
}
int main() {

  string s;

  while(s.size() < 6) getline(cin, s);

  int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0;

  x1 = s[0] - 'a';
  y1 = s[1] - '1';
  x2 = s[4] - 'a';
  y2 = s[5] - '1';

  if(h(x1, y1, x2, y2)) cout << 1;
  else {
    if(h(x1 + 2, y1 + 1, x2, y2) || h(x1 + 2, y1 - 1, x2, y2) || h(x1 - 2, y1 + 1, x2, y2) || h(x1 - 2, y1 - 1, x2, y2) || h(x1 + 1, y1 + 2, x2, y2) || h(x1 + 1, y1 - 2, x2, y2) || h(x1 - 1, y1 + 2, x2, y2) || h(x1 - 1, y1 - 2, x2, y2))
      cout << 2;
    else cout << "NO";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: проблема видимо в том, что вы не учитываете, тот вариант, что они попадут в одну клетку, но она будёт вне поля

Comment: @GGO я добавил еще один код к себе в вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста, вы это имели в виду? тоже валит

Comment: ниже уже @Harry расписал как можно лучше сделать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Большое у меня подозрение, что вы не учитываете, что на первом ходу можете выскочить за пределы доски. И, например, считаете допустимой последовательность a8-b10-c8...

Вот примерный вариант, который все учитывает:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool ok(int mx, int my, int nx, int ny)
{
    if (mx < 0 || mx > 7) return false;
    if (my < 0 || my > 7) return false;
    if (nx < 0 || nx > 7) return false;
    if (ny < 0 || ny > 7) return false;
    return
        (abs(mx-nx)==2 && abs(my-ny)==1)||
        (abs(mx-nx)==1 && abs(my-ny)==2);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int nx,ny,mx,my;
    string s;
    cin>> s;
    nx = s[0]-'a'; ny = s[1]-'1';
    cin>> s;
    mx = s[0]-'a'; my = s[1]-'1';

    // 1 ход
    if (ok(mx,my,nx,ny)) { cout << "1\n"; return 0; }

    int dx[] = { -2, -2, -1, -1,  1,  1,  2,  2 };
    int dy[] = { -1,  1, -2,  2, -2,  2, -1,  1 };

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        if (ok(mx+dx[i],my+dy[i],nx,ny))
            { cout << "2\n"; return 0; }
    }
    cout << "NO\n";
}
```

Comment: Синхронно с вами вписал такую же проверку в свой код, спасибо за ответ!)
Мой окончательный код, если кому-то понадобится : https://ideone.com/DMhDKn